# Download data to Excel from a web widget in icCube

Tags: excel, widget, iccube

Is it possible to add additional information on the table that is downloaded to Excel from an icCube widget.

Now, only the labels on the columns and rows is displayed, including - of course - with the formatted data.

Is it also possible to show the labels in the WHERE/SUB QUERY statement.
That would give the user the context of the data downloaded.
[image: pivot table in icCube with buttons to select the year filter]
[image: Download result to Excel as it is now]

Comment: Hi Arthur, Did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: No, I am hoping for an icCube update that supports this.

Comment: Did someone find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

On icCube 5.1.3 Reporting you must to pick a button from tools/utilities option and place it, now edit it, in the items wizard tab ,click on + and add a new item,fill the "caption" and "event name" fields, now edit your icCube object and go to the events tab put the name of the event in your button("event name")  in the "do Export To Excel" field.

Comment: Sorry Francisco, for me, doing this you just add an export to excel button... Nothing to see with question asked...